# How to Extract a String from a URL and Replace % with Space?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to find a way to extract text from a string in Google Data Studio:

Sample Pagename:

```
https://xx.site.com/group/analytics/search?param=department%20of%20army
```

I want to strip out:

```
department%20of%20arm
```

and have it be:

```
department of army
```

The search string could be many different things and many different lengths but the below will always be the same:

```
https://xx.site.com/group/analytics/search?param=
```

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below first uses the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function to capture all characters after `?param=` and then incorporates the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) function to remove `%` followed by any digits `\\d+` and replaces it with a   (space):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Field, "\\?param=(.*)$"), "(%\\d+)", " ")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4a3cf350-9787-4fd6-98e9-dc57096358eb/page/RseiB) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]